# Automate Oracle Apex page layout

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

Can I automate or adjust oracle apex page layout and not individual region. I have a page where multiple regions are there and one region is master region, I want to set something on the page itself at horizontal scrollbar region by region doesn't look good.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you want to achieve?  I can't visualise from your description.

Comment: Added in attachement

Comment: Thanks for the picture, but I still don't understand your question.  "I want to set something on the page itself at horizontal scrollbar" - what does that mean?

Comment: the 2nd image that I attached shows correct page layout when I zoomed out the page. But default would be 100%. Can we do something in the settings that will automate this layout.

Comment: OK, so what you want is to remove the **vertical** (not horizontal) scroll bar, not add a horizontal scroll bar?  You want the page to be automatically zoomed out sufficiently to show the whole page without scrolling - is that it?

Comment: Page is big vertical scroll bar is fine I don't want to add scroll bar and if so items should not be cut when the page exceeds it should automatic adjustable. I thought there is no option to do so I added horizontal scroll bar as item field was cut